# Prove: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}}{ \ln(n) } = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm not completely new to convergent series and sequences, but proving the above gave me some troubles. Would appreciate some help :)

Show that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}}{ \ln(n) } = 1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By approximating the sum with integrals (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Approximation_by_definite_integrals)),
$$
\ln(n+1)=\int_1^{n+1}\frac1x\mathrm dx\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le 1+\int_1^n\frac1x\mathrm dx=1+\ln n
$$
since $1/k$ is decreasing for $k\ge 1$. We have that
$$
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}=\frac{\ln n+\ln(1+\frac1n)}{\ln n}\to1
$$
as $n\to\infty$ and we obtain the result.

Comment: Nice use of the sandwich theorem.

Comment: Very nice indeed! Thank you :)

Comment: @Anil You're welcome! Also, consider upvoting the answers that you like and accepting the best answer.

Comment: Can I pick only one best answer? :')

Comment: Yes, only one answer can be accepted. You can find more information about voting [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 4):

One can also use the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Write

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k}{\ln n} = \frac{a_n}{b_n}.$$
As

$$\begin{split}
\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_n} &= \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\ln (n+1)- \ln n} \\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1) \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)} \\
&= \left(\ln\left(\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^n\left(1 + \frac 1n\right) \right)\right)^{-1} \\
&\to (\ln (e))^{-1} = 1,
\end{split}$$

then 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1.$$

Comment: I was unaware of this theorem, thank you kindly! :)

Answer (score 3):

Starting with
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}}{ \log(n) }$$
Notice that the numerator represents the Harmonic numbers, so we rewrite this as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{H_n}{ \log(n) }$$
Now, $H_n \sim \log(n) + \gamma$ for big $n$, where $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. Plugging this in, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n) + \gamma}{ \log(n) }$$
$$ 1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\gamma}{ \log(n) }$$
$$= 1$$

[**Source**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation)

Comment: A bit less elegant than the other two proves, but thank you nonetheless :) It helps!